# How to make my computer as a public server in NodeJS or any other way?

Tags: node.js, server

I want to make my computer as a public server. I tried to it with following code with NodeJS. Instead of giving hostname as 127.0.0.1 i maked it with my real ip address. but it didn't works. what is the reason? Is it possible to create a public server in that way? Or Is there any other alternative ways?

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '175.157.210.25';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server2 running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

output

```
C:\Users\Nuwanst\Documents\NodeJS\test2>node app.js
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 175.157.210.25:3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1245:19)
    at listen (net.js:1294:10)
    at net.js:1404:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:83:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)

C:\Users\Nuwanst\Documents\NodeJS\test2>node app.js
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 175.157.210.25:3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1245:19)
    at listen (net.js:1294:10)
    at net.js:1404:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:83:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

Comment: why the php tag?

Comment: my be alternative solution can be there.

Comment: also is port 3000 open on your machine's firewall and is your modem/router configured to have that port accessible from external IPs, and for requests at that port to go through to your machine?

Comment: what if i give port 80?

Comment: I am not sure about your way but there is an alternative way to do this. You can use the Localtunnel  ( https://localtunnel.github.io/www/)

Comment: thanks that's what I'm expecting. This method might be worthless. But I want to know the alternative ways to doing that.